# What should one consider before signing contract with a microstock agency like Getty?

Tags: flickr, contracts, commercial-photography, micro-stock

Getty has shown interest in some of my images in flickr. This is my first time experience with microstock agencies. I am kind of nervous as well as excited. Is there anything in particular I should know or be aware of before involving in this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, Getty isn't really microstock, they're probably the king of stock photography in general. The only thing I would be reluctant about with Getty is some [recent behavior](http://www.aphotoeditor.com/2011/05/09/apa-recommends-that-members-do-not-sign-getty-agreement/) around their treatment of longtime artistic photographers under contract.

So, I think Getty is counting on good amateur photographers being excited about possibly getting published, maybe earning a little bit for their images, that they're using it as a hammer on people who previously dedicated their work to it. It doesn't speak well for Getty in my opinion.

Comment: Actions like that by industry giants like Getty are so depressing. Is there not even a smidgen of honor and respect left in commerce anymore?

Comment: @jrista - Yeah, it's pretty sad how they're now looking to eat the people that got them there.

Comment: I am sorry but what part of the contract shall I be worried about? Can someone please point it out here for future reference?

Comment: @ShutterBug - It's not specifically that you should be worried, it's that Getty decided that they had enough of a hammer to screw contracted photographers. So, sad to say, but you're intended to be a part of that hammer.

Comment: So, what you're are saying is, they are trying to build up enough muscle by making contracts with lots of entry level photographers so that they can force the top contributors to stay within the same getty-centric contract?

Comment: @ShutterBug - Read the link I included, I think if you follow the chain of information there (Google if you need), you'll see the picture. I'm not necessarily suggesting that you don't agree to terms with Getty, I'm just noting that Getty seems pretty easy going with moving their terms to suit as they feel like it. Go into that with eyes wide open.